# How can I play the particle System when the player collides with point

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a collecting effect of point for player by using Particle System. But when the player collides with the point the particle system does not play. But point gets collected.

Thanks in advance.

This is my particle script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ParticleScripts : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().Play();
        GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = false;
    }
}
```

I tried this thinking that it will work.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ParticleScripts : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool SpriteRenderer = true;

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().Play();
        GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are deactivating the collected object before the particle system gets a chance to start. You can do this another way and instantiate the particle system at the location of the point you picked up. This will allow the particle system to play out even if the point has been destroyed or hidden.

Comment: Is your game 2d? If not this collision wont trigger. It would also need the rigidbody2d and a 2d collider to work.

Comment: Yes, my game is 2d.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, you are disabling the `Point` object which is the parent of your `ParticleSystem`. This is why the effect is not displayed. To fix this, create a `Prefab` of your particle system and set its `PlayOnAwake` property to true and instantiate it when the collision happens.

Something like this:

```
public ParticleSystem MyPrefab;
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    Instantiate(MyPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = false;
}
```

Keep in mind that you will need to dispose of the instantiated object later on.

You can attach something like this to your prefab so it destroys itself after some time and it doesn't use up your resources.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class DestroyOnTime : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        // Destroy the current GameObject after 2 seconds
        Destroy(gameObject, 2f);
    }
}
```

Comment: If i turn on PlayOnAwake the particles plays when the point spawns.

Comment: That is why you need to create a prefab for it instead of attaching it directly to the point. You can create an empty object and attach the `PartycleSystem` to it and then save the empty object as a prefab. Reference the prefab by dragging it into the `MyPrefab` property of your point object inside the inspector.

Comment: Sorry but i can't do and you helped me so much. but its doing the same thing plays on when the point spawns.

Comment: If you managed to create the prefab and referenced it on your point object, you probably forgot to remove the attached `ParticleSystem` from your point object.